# Rcpp no matching function for call to abs

Tags: r, rcpp

when using Rcpp, I want to use function `abs`, I just write `Rcpp::abs(-1)`, but always an error:

> no matching function for call to abs

Actually when I write `Rcpp:ab`, there are some hint that there exists `Rcpp::abs()`. I have tried some other function `Rcpp::NumericVector`, it works. I know I can use `std::abs(-1)`, I just wonder why `Rcpp::abs(-1)` do not work, my system is windows, and I install Rtools.

Answer (score 2):

[`Rcpp::abs()`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/6f81b4684481dbd9bb554dd95e66725fc3b63a8c/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/math.h#L42) requires an *Rcpp* object, e.g. `*Vector` and `*Matrix`.

Unfortunately, `-1` is of a primitive type, e.g. *not* an *Rcpp* object.

So, the following would work:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void show_rcpp_abs() {
    Rcpp::NumericVector A = NumericVector::create(-1);
    Rcpp::Rcout << "A" << Rcpp::abs(A) << std::endl;

    double B = std::abs(-1.0);
    Rcpp::Rcout << "B" << B << std::endl;
}
```